# Add returned data from ajax call to a UL then update jQuery quicksand

Tags: javascript, jquery, quicksand

I'm building a list of users and trying to use jQuery [quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/docs-and-demos.html) to update the UL based upon the returned data from an ajax request.

The data is requested like so:

```
$.webMethod({
    url: 'http://staging.cmdapp.com/Services/Poll.asmx/LeaderboardGetTopScores',
    data: '{quizIDs:"'+quizIDs+'",numRecords:"'+numRecords+'"}',
    beforeSend: function () { },
    success: function (ret) {

        $.each(ret.leaderboard,function(i){
            // do something     
        });  

    },
    error: function (response) { console.log(response.responseText); }
});
```

The returned data is a JSON string and each user is defined by 'user_id'. JSON data (sorry for unformatted):

```
{"d":"{\"leaderboard\":[{\"user_id\":\"8\",\"first_name\":\"Kevin\",\"last_name\":\"McFarlane\",\"points\":\"1\",\"time_taken\":1408,\"incorrect_attempts\":0},{\"user_id\":\"9\",\"first_name\":\"Hanna\",\"last_name\":\"Gilbert\",\"points\":\"1\",\"time_taken\":4762,\"incorrect_attempts\":0},{\"user_id\":\"1\",\"first_name\":\"Adrian\",\"last_name\":\"Bathurst\",\"points\":\"0\",\"time_taken\":1616,\"incorrect_attempts\":0}]}"}
```

In my html page I have the quicksand list ready like so:

```
<ul class="quicksand">
    <li data-id="1">1</li>
    <li data-id="2">2</li>
    <li data-id="3">3</li>
    <li data-id="4">4</li>
</ul>
```

I now want to update the UL on every ajax request. How can I store the returned data and add each separate 'user' in a separate LI item?

I tried the following but no luck:

```
$.webMethod({
    url: 'http://staging.cmdapp.com/Services/Poll.asmx/LeaderboardGetTopScores',
    data: '{quizIDs:"'+quizIDs+'",numRecords:"'+numRecords+'"}',
    beforeSend: function () { },
    success: function (ret) {

        $.each(ret.leaderboard,function(i){
            pos = i + 1;
            str = '<li data-id="'+pos+'">' + ret.leaderboard[i].first_name + '&nbsp;' + ret.leaderboard[i].last_name + '</li>';       
        });

        $('.quicksand').quicksand( str, { adjustHeight: 'dynamic' } );     
        console.log(str);              
    },
    error: function (response) { console.log(response.responseText); }
});
```

It maybe worth noting that I **can** see the correct data in each LI items being pulled in every ajax request into the DOM, but it disapears immedietely and only the first LI item is displayed.

Comment: can you post the json blob here please

Comment: Done. JSON prettifier isn't working on it for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is incorrect. The value for the key `d` is actually a string here and not an object and that is the reason you feel that the JSON Formatter is not working. Its actually working but is treating it like a string instead on an Object.

You have to unwrap the quotes to treat it like an object or use `$.parseJSON` to convert it into an object.

```
$.webMethod({
    url: 'http://staging.cmdapp.com/Services/Poll.asmx/LeaderboardGetTopScores',
    data: '{quizIDs:"'+quizIDs+'",numRecords:"'+numRecords+'"}',
    beforeSend: function () { },
    success: function (ret) {

        ret = $.parseJSON(ret.d);

        $.each(ret.leaderboard,function(i){
            pos = i + 1;
            str = '<li data-id="'+pos+'">' + ret.leaderboard[i].first_name + '&nbsp;' + ret.leaderboard[i].last_name + '</li>';       
        });

        $('.quicksand').quicksand( str, { adjustHeight: 'dynamic' } );     
        console.log(str);              
    },
    error: function (response) { console.log(response.responseText); }
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rttAZ/

Comment: Hmm, that seems to return 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'leaderboard' of null'

Comment: wait.. is `$` = `jQuery` here?

Comment: try fiddling around. Do you know to use a debugger? Firebug? Because its working in my jsFiddle and I cant think of any reason why it isn't working on your page.